# Attempting to end anything running of port 3306

Tags: mysql, port, mamp

I have MAMP Pro running on OS X 10.7.2 and it uses port 3306 for MYSQL. It was running fine until this morning when I installed a trial of WebStart. I subsequently did not like Webstart and quit and uninstalled it. My problem now is that MAMP Pro will not Start MYSQL. The log shows:

```
Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or   log files.
```

I ran this in terminal:

```
lsof -i:3306
```

... and it returned:

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  3966 _mysql   10u  IPv4 0xffffff802505c880      0t0  TCP localhost:mysql (LISTEN)
```

However, I am not really sure what this means and what to do. I suspect that WebStart put this other process in place for port 3306.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is already a MySQL Server Daemon process running on 3306 as PID 3966.  It could easily be a leftover process from what appears to be a fairly unclean uninstall.  You can kill the process in a variety of ways including (but not limited to):

```
pkill mysqld
kill -9 3966
```

You can verify it is gone by running the lsof command again or:

```
ps -ef | grep mysqld
```

Once you are sure the process is gone your MAMP instance of MySQL should be able to start.

Comment: Only use kill -9 as a last resort! you should start with using the normal startup/shutdown scripts and/or commands like `service` to start or stop the processes.

Comment: @Zypher running under the assumption the normal scripts are gone since he uninstalled the application, but I otherwise agree.

Comment: Thanks I had to use `kill -9 3966' (had to switch to su), restarted my computer and MAMP Pro works normally now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also kill all pids running on a port with the following if you want to more blindly do it

```
fuser -k 3306/tcp
```

Comment: Unknown option: k